# Using path.exist in if statement (syntax error)

Tags: python, if-statement, path, syntax-error

I am trying to test the validity paths provided by a user as part of a more complex script.

I have created simplified versions of my script to find that I am not using the path.exists command correctly. I want to use the output of `True` or `False` to guide my `if` statement but it is not working.

I have tried multiple variations of the following:

```
# get the module I need
import os.path
from os import path

# use a random path just to test for functionality
test_path = "/my/test/path"

#Create a variable based on whether the path actually exists
#so that `True` or `False` can be used in subsequent `if` statements 
#and other decision making processes   
authenticity_test = path.exists(test_path)

#a basic check to see if the variable is actually being set correctly
#(it seems to be)
print(authenticity_test)

#Simplified if statement using only `print()` commands that peristently fails
if authenticity_test = True
    print("Is True")
else:
    print("Is False")
```

I have also tried using strings e.g. replacing

```
authenticity_test = path.exists(test_path)
```

with

```
authenticity_test = str(path.exists(test_path))
```

and then using

```
 if authenticity_test = "True"
```

The error always seems to occur on this line:

```
if authenticity_test = True

Error: File "<ipython-input-74-c28cf8149b8b>", line 1
if authenticity_test = True
                     ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Comment: `=` is the assignment operator. `==` is the comparison operator. But you just need `if authenticity_test:`

Comment: You should use comparison operator (==) instead of assignment operator (=) in if condition

Answer (score 1, accepted):

correction

```
if authenticity_test:
```

or

```
if authenticity_test==True:
```

Comment: Please give a short but helpful description of your suggested solution. Answers that are just a simple corrected code line are not considered to be of good quality.